# How can I run VisualWorks under OpenBSD?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, openbsd, visualworks

Has anyone gotten VisualWorks running under OpenBSD? It's not an officially supported platform, but one of the Cincom guys was telling me that it should be able to run under a linux compatibility mode. How did you set it up?

I already have Squeak running without a problem, so I'm not looking for an alternative. I specifically need to run VisualWorks's Web Velocity for a project.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the [OpenBSD FAQ](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/), specifically section [9.4 - Running Linux Binaries on OpenBSD](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq9.html#Interact).

Typically there are more steps needed then just `kern.emul.linux=1` unless you have statically linked (i.e. completely stand-alone) binaries. The good news is that packages exist that contain Linux libs, and they are easy to install. This is all detailed in the above link.

Answer (score 5):

if you're wondering about setting up linux compatibility mode and you're running the GENERIC kernel:

```
# sysctl kern.emul.linux=1
```

to enable at boot uncomment the kern.emul.linux=1 line in /etc/sysctl.conf